# Words to say when you don't want to speak about it otherwise it might come true

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, thought

How do you say a situation wherein you are thinking of something negative while not speaking about it otherwise it might come true.

Conversely, it could also be a situation wherein you are not verbalizing a hopeful thought fearing the positive situation might reverse.

Comment: Don't leave answers as comments; leave answers as answers. Comments don't have the quality assurance mechanisms that answers do.

Answer (score 6):

The second one would be "I don't want to jinx it", but I don't think it applies to the first situation.

Comment: +1 A perfectly good response to the second situation.

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of an expression for remaining *silent* out of fear of something happening if you were to actually express a thought.

It could be an example of **superstition**, but that's not very specific.

---

The closest thing I could think of—and which is more appropriate for the *title* of this question rather than its detail—is the phrase [**knock on wood**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/knock_on_wood):

> [Oxford]
>
> *North American*
>
> Said in order to prevent a confident statement from bringing bad luck.
>
> ‘I have never, knock on wood, been typecast’
> ‘I used direct deposit, it hasn't been a problem as of yet, knock on wood.’

This is contrasted to [**touch wood**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/touch_wood), which is the UK version and has the same meaning:

> [Oxford]
>
> *British*
>
> Said in order to prevent a confident statement from bringing bad luck.
>
> ‘I haven't been banned yet, touch wood’
> ‘We haven't had a fatal accident in the village yet, touch wood, but we don't want to sit back and wait for that to happen.’

---

Answer (score 3):

The 1st situation can be described as trying to avoid a [self-fulfilling prophecy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-fulfilling-prophecy): *something that you cause to happen by saying and expecting that it will happen.*

The 2nd situation, as user Pantera Onca already [answered](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/453723/90409), is commonly referred to as a *jinx*.

Comment: I don't think the first part exactly fits: "that you cause to happen by saying and expecting that it will happen". OP stated they wouldn't speak about the negative thing: "thinking... while not speaking about it otherwise it might come true". And the inference is that since it wasn't spoken of, the negative thing probably wouldn't happen, at least not as a result of avoiding to speak about it.